# How to apply style in WPF Grid's first row at run time

Tags: .net, wpf, grid, styles

How to apply style in WPF Grid's first row at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this -

```
    Style style = new Style(typeof(RowDefinition));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(RowDefinition.HeightProperty, 10));

    yourGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Style = style;
```

Update:

You can use [FrameworkElement.FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) Method to find your style.

Check this for more details -

[Resources and Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752326.aspx)

Comment: i have already defined a style in a "myTheame.xaml" so at runtime how to read style from "myTheame.xaml" and to apply it on grid's row.